# Hyper-V over the cloud

Tags: virtualization, dropbox, hyper-v, onedrive, cloud

I have multiple work computers (including desktops and laptops) and would like to access a single Hyper-V VM for a specific development so that I can use my nearest dev machine - including when I am working remotely.

Is it possible to share a VM using a cloud service such as Dropbox or OneDrive?

Comment: I don’t think putting an entire virtual disk in Dropbox is going to scale very well. You’d probably have very long sync times, even with delta syncing.

Comment: It would be one VM, PC most used, every few weeks using laptop on a  visit. Bandwidth not a problem (Europe not US). No need for scaling.

Comment: Bandwidth is *always* a problem, even in Europe. We’re talking about at least 10 GiB, I believe. You need to keep in mind that the delta sync algorithm won’t work properly with disk images where data may be fragmented and whatnot.

Comment: Thinking about more useful info: VM will be used on laptop when away and synched when on LAN. Even if over net, a 10GiB file takes no more than 30ish mins.

Answer (score 0):

No, DropBox and OneDrive or for sharing files and each service has their own unique API, none of which to my knowledge allow you to share a VM hard drive image without download the whole image first to the machine hosting the virtual machine.

You'll probably have better results hosting the VM remotely on a single machine, and then using services like Remote Desktop to connect to the VM over the internet.

Without more information on what you're trying to accomplish exactly, I can't say for sure what the best solution would be.

Comment: I can not guarantee the uptime of the main host. Placing the VM in cloud storage is not a problem - but separate hosts generate unique IDs for the VMs causing synchronization problems. If there is a better idea I am open

Comment: Granted I'm not familiar with Hyper-V to that extent, but the first thing that comes to mind is: figure out where the unique ids are saved, and modify them during the sync to match each other. I can't say for sure what the implications of this would be though.